Java EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Error with jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll
I am encountering a fatal error when running my Java application, and I need help diagnosing the issue. The error message I receive is as follows:
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007110b5db, pid=20472, tid=0x0000000000003594 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_421) (build 1.8.0_421-b09) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.421-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops) Problematic frame: C  [jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll+0xb5db] Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows An error report file with more information is saved as: C:\Users\Atharva\hs_err_pid20472.log
Details:
Java version: 1.8.0_421
Operating System: Windows (details about the version would be helpful)
Library in use: jSSC version 2.8
The crash seems to occur outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
I have checked the error report file located at C:\Users\Atharva\hs_err_pid20472.log, but I’m unsure how to interpret it.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? What steps can I take to resolve the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error related to the jSSC library? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Updated Java:
Checked the latest version of Java 8 if the application supports it.
Check Compatibility:
Checked that the version of jSSC in use is compatible with the Java version.
